# Magento 2 returns 404 after switching language on product pages

Tags: products, magento2.1.5

magento 2 one store click on product page giving 
www.abc.com/product1.html after switch on next language

it showing like this

catalog/product/view/id/15/s/tablets

if have any idea please tell me

Answer (score 0):

This Issue occur, if the product was created before adding the new website/store/storeview (in other words website/store/storeview created after product is added).
because Url rewrite for the product for that new storeview is not created so the url will be something like this  `catalog/product/view/id/15/s/tablets`

One way to resolve this is, open the product in edit mode on backend and just save it. This will create rewrite Url for all available storeview.

Comment: it did this but not solved. http://www.text.com/carlson-norwegian-salmon-oil-omega-3s-epa-dha-180-50-softgels.html this url is for my english store. while switch in to another language store giving 404 error. but in another store url look like http://www.text.com/product/view/id/890/s/carlson-norwegian-salmon-oil-omega-3s-epa-dha-180-50-softgels/

Comment: have you created product before creating store ? Have you created a new Store view or Website ?

Comment: try reindexing and cache clean

Comment: i created store views after that only imported products but each store having different names i tried re index and cache